# Save and load listbox items added by user in c# with windows form app

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to save listbox items not to a text file, but save them so that when an item is added to the listbox and the application is closed, upon opening the application the item added to the listbox will still be present.

Use case:

- User opens application.
- User adds item called "Item 1" to listbox using button.
- User closes application.
- User opens application again and sees that "Item 1" is still in the listbox, and the added item hasn't been lost by the application closing.

I've seen people succeed in doing something like this with textbox data (this video for example: [saving user settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P432z8q9iVE)), but am having trouble getting it to work with listbox data.

Here's how I attempted to do it myself based on the linked video beginning with the button the user uses to add an item to the listbox:

```
private void AddTeamButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // add the item to the listbox
      listBox1.Items.Add("Example string);
      // add the item to the ListBoxStuff settings 
      Settings.Default["ListBoxStuff"] = Settings.Default["ListBoxStuff"] + "|" + "Example string";
    }
```

Then upon the form loading:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // needs to stay
    {

        // Items from the ListBoxStuff setting is saved as a string - this may be the issue, but am unsure, this gets the values of the settings?
        string listboxItems = Settings.Default["ListBoxStuff"].ToString();

        // If there are values other than null or empty.
        if (listboxItems != null || !listboxItems.Equals(""))
        {
            string[] separators = { "|" };
            // Put the items in a string array, splitting them at the | which means the next item in the string
            string[] itemsToAdd = listboxItems.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // Loop through the array
            foreach (string i in itemsToAdd)
            {
                // Add each item to the list box
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

My thinking was that every time a user adds an item to the list, the listboxstuff string has the item added to it with a | inbetween, upon loading, we get this string, split it at every |, and add each item in the newly created array to the listbox, and if it's empty, nothing happens.

But the result is that the item added to the listbox is not there upon reopening the application after adding an item.

Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the settings

```
private void AddTeamButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // add the item to the listbox
  listBox1.Items.Add("Example string);
  // add the item to the ListBoxStuff settings 
  Settings.Default["ListBoxStuff"] = Settings.Default["ListBoxStuff"] + "|" + "Example string";
  Settings.Default.Save();
}
```